# Segmenting Permutations For Multitasking Java

Tags: c#, java, android, arrays, algorithm

I have and array that can take any number of points, and the points are given an index.

Then I am running a non recursive solution that creates all permutations

It runs through `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0` and ends with `0,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1`
this has a time complexity to it

Now, I would like to find the middle point of these permutations 
so that I can run the pattern from the start and the middle with threads to reduce the time complexity.

How would I find the middle point?.

In Java:

```
    public Path QuickPerm(int[] points) {
       int N = points.length;
       int a[] = points ;
       int p[] = new int[N];
       Path shortest = null;
       Path current = null;
       int i;
       int j;
       int tmp; // Upper Index i; Lower Index j
       for(int i1 = 0; i1 < N; i1++) {  
          p[i1] = 0;       // p[i] == i controls iteration and index boundaries for i
       }
       //display(a, 0, 0);   // remove comment to display array a[]
       i = 1;   // setup first swap points to be 1 and 0 respectively (i & j)
       while(i < N) {
          if (p[i] < i) {
             j = i % 2 * p[i];   // IF i is odd then j = p[i] otherwise j = 0
             tmp = a[j];         // swap(a[j], a[i])
             a[j] = a[i];
             a[i] = tmp;
                                 //save 
             p[i]++;             // increase index "weight" for i by one
             i = 1;              // reset index i to 1 (assumed)
          } else {               // otherwise p[i] == i
             p[i] = 0;           // reset p[i] to zero
             i++;                // set new index value for i (increase by one)
          } // if (p[i] < i)
       }
       return shortest;// while(i < N)
    } // QuickPerm()
```

Comment: why is this tagged c#?

Comment: because ill except a c# answer

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code describes one way of numbering permutations so that you can decide e.g. to take a number half way along and find out what permutation it is.

Depending on what your threads do you might find that not all permutations take the same amount of time, so splitting the list of permutations half way along does not balance the work exactly. One way people have handled this is to split the work into a large number of small pieces, and have your threads pick a small piece of work any time they have nothing to do. Then it doesn't matter so much if some pieces of work take longer than others - the threads that get stuck with them will simply end up working on a smaller number of pieces but taking much the same time.

Comment: I have thought of this but i cant see how i can break the series up.
for example how would i break up the permutations if N = 50?

Comment: N=50 sounds pretty ambitious, but the idea is probably the same - you can fix the first two elements in the permutation in (50 chose 2) different ways. For each of those ways you can then permute the 48 remaining elements in 48! different ways - these (50 chose 2) subdivisions are (relatively) small chunks of work, each of which contains only 48! permutations to check - have you done any rough estimates to work out how long it will take to check 50! permutations - simply typing 50! at google suggests to me that there are 3.0414093e+64 of them.

Comment: i am aware of the time implications a traveling salesman to a 100 should take a year hence why im trying to split the load into segments so i can track the progress and run each segment on a different thread.

Comment: im using a galaxy s4's 8 core processor to measure how long it would take to proccess a traveling salesman 100. - this is a project ive wanted to work on since varsity.
the only reason its in java and not c# is because http://xamarin.com/ runs slow as hell.
i am at the point of just taking 100 random arrays order from low to high and then running quickperms() on threads with the start or end value of the order

Answer (score 0):

Using a next-permutation algorithm that uses lexico-order would make this a piece of cake, see e.g. wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order

(Check the middle index for a few values of n, and you'll immediately see the pattern, e.g. for 1234, element 12 in a zero-indexed sequence would be 1243, and for 12345 the element 60 would be 12354.)

Comment: how would lexico-order give me the start and end values of the segments

Comment: Assuming that your path must visit all points: if complexity is important to you, then you might want to check out the dynammic programming approach to solve TSP which runs in O(2^n*n^2) which is way better than going over all permutations and determining the path length. I think that idea can be applicable in your case as well. Guess it depends on N if it's worth it... If the path doesn't have to visit all points you likely have an easy shortest path problem!

Comment: N is a 100. ive looked at that recursive solution and the only way that i could map and segment the algorithm is by using a non recursive solution

Comment: @Jaycin Van Vuuren can you please describe the problem in more detail, in particular the cost function. If you're "only solving" a TSP with 100 nodes, you're in very good shape, but if your cost depends on the order, and not only distances, you're not as lucky ...

Comment: I have an array set of 4950 routes that allows my points to find the distance when I create the route object. for this part i am simply looking at the order. ill record the shortest of each segment in an attempt to find the shortest combination.

Comment: i still think limiting quickperm() to a start and end array.
generating 100 int[100] unique random arrays  and ordering from low to high and running my permutation code between these points them would result in me running 100 segments. but then again the last segment could only start half way ect. id rather just call a method that would tell me if 1,2,3,4,5 is the start then 3,2,1,4,5 is the middle and 5,4,3,2,1 is the end that would give me exact segments

Comment: @Jaycin Van Vuuren: I still don't get the original problem, can you please describe the problem in even more detail.

Comment: at this point my applications generates 4950 possible routes to allow me to create paths. now i have a way of creating path objects with these route objects. so all i need to do is run every permutation of an int[x] for my test x = 100. now i cant map how long or how far my quick perm method is. so i would like to create segment points along the exponential amount of combinations so i can use threading to lower the time complexity and track how far the algorithm is. as i said i thought of using an ordered list of unique arrays to create dummy segments of random size but that is pointless